# Xcode 12.5.1 getting this error , any idea?

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to upload the app on App Store but getting this error, what am I doing wrong? Xcode version 12.5.1, game not even run in the simulator, do I need a device to connect or what?

[image: see screenshot here]

```
error: ignoring file BBPlayer/Frameworks/AOBSessionReporting.framework/AOBSessionReporting, missing required architecture x86_64 in file BBPlayer/Frameworks/AOBSessionReporting.framework/AOBSessionReporting (2 slices)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is an issue with the M1 chip Macs. I think many third-party frameworks do not yet support simulation on M1 Macs. If you're trying to use Product > Archive in the menu bar, make sure you have "Any iOS Device" selected as your build device.

Comment: as i guess i need ios device to be connected right? to archive

Comment: You do not need to connect an iOS device to archive, no. In the dropdown menu of where you would select a simulator device, just scroll until you see "Any iOS Device" and click it. Then hover over "Product" in the menu bar and click Archive.

Comment: oh my god bro thank u so much, u have no idea how long i am searching for solve problem <3 broooo thaaank uuuuuuuuuuuuu <3 <3 <3 <3

Comment: @JackWilliams Please mark my answer as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

you must close your Xcode and go to the Application folder
right-click on the Xcode application and click "Get Info"
after that, you must check change to true the "Open Using Rosetta"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dleH.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9rVg.png)